# Web scraping in Selenium (Python) throws Element Not Found

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to scrape Chinese economic data from an official website, but I keep getting an Element Not Found exception on the last line here. I've scoured stackoverflow and have tried adding implicitly_wait and switching the problem line from xpath to ID, but nothing has worked. Any thoughts?

```
from selenium import webdriver


FAI = []
FAIinfra = []
FAIestate = []

path_to_chromedriver = '/Users/cargillsk/Downloads/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)

browser.implicitly_wait(30)

url = 'http://www.cqdata.gov.cn/easyquery.htm?cn=A0101'
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_id('treeZhiBiao_4').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*
[@id="mySelect_sj"]/div[2]/div[1]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*
[@id="mySelect_sj"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/input').clear()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*
[@id="mySelect_sj"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/input').send_keys('last100')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*
[@id="mySelect_sj"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]').click()
FAIinitial = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-container"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/thead/tr/th[2]/strong').text

for i in range(2,102):
    i = str(i)
    FAI.append(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="table_main"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[%s]' % i).text)
    FAIinfra.append(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="table_main"]/tbody/tr[4]/td[%s]' % i).text)
    FAIestate.append(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="table_main"]/tbody/tr[55]/td[%s]' % i).text)

browser.find_element_by_id("treeZhiBiao_3").click()
browser.find_element_by_id("treeZhiBiao_14").click()
```

Comment: try refocusing `browser.switch_to.active_element`

Comment: you scoured the stackover flow and only thing you found is implicit wait and changing xpath to id, how about explicit wait, iframe?

Comment: Gaurang, I apologize if I sound stupid sometimes, but I'm trying very hard to self-teach Python and I'm only a few weeks in. Re: your comment, my understanding is that if implicit wait doesn't work, neither will explicit wait, because the former covers the entire program.  I looked through the html for frames but found none.  Redp, thank you for your tip but unfortunately it didn't work for me. Still can't figure this one out.

Comment: If this helps at all, every once in a while it (seemingly randomly) works. I can't figure out why it doesn't work the vast majority of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... the implicit wait is not your issue. Looking through the websites code I found that there is no "treeZhiBiao_14", so I'm not sure what your trying to click here. Maybe try using something like this instead so you know what your clicking.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '工业')]").click()
```

or

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'industry')]").click()
```

Comment: wow this worked- thank you so much. "treeZhiBiao_14" is definitely in the code i'm looking at...but i'm not going worry about that because i've been staring at this problem for a full week! thanks again for your help.

Comment: No problem! Definitely try using less direct paths, sometimes websites can change or move the location of an element, which would totally mess up your code.